# What is the Story behind Niradri Bije?

Tags: vishnu, gods, rituals

Niradri Bije is a Post Ritual of Jagannath Rath Yatra .What is the mythological Significance of this ritual and how is it celebrated ?
What is the Story behind Niradri Bije ?

Answer (score 1):

‘**Niladri**’ suggests Lord Jagannath and ‘**Bije**’ means to enter. This is really interesting as it is all about the continuation of the fight between Lord Jagannath and Goddess Laxmi. Lord Balabhadra and Subhadra entered the temple after they return from the vacation but Lord Jagannath was not allowed to enter.

A fight happened between Lord Jagannath and Laxmi in front of the temple. Goddess Laxmi was angry on him as he had not taken her along for the vacation to his aunt’s place. He had also closed the door when the Goddess had come to meet him. The angry Goddess Laxmi didn’t want him to enter the temple as he had disrespected her.

Even after a lot of requests, Lord Jagannath was not allowed to enter the temple premises.  It was only after he offered 'Rasgullas' an Oriya sweet made of curd and cheese to Goddess Laxmi, she calmed down. She then accepted his apology and allowed him to enter the temple.

Comment: You can cite some source.